# Unset all attributes backbone at once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got a question about Backbone, how is it possible to set all attributes of a model to empty?

```
unsetmodel.unset(attribute, [options]) 
Remove an attribute by deleting it from the internal attributes hash. Fires a "change" event unless silent is passed as an option.
```

But this is only meant for unsetting individual properties one by one.

Anyone an idea?

Gretz,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Backbone site:

> **clearmodel.clear([options])**
>
> Removes all attributes from the model, including the id attribute.
>   Fires a "change" event unless silent is passed as an option.

So I would do something like:

```
myModel.clear();
```

---

If you want to keep the attributes, why not iterate through all of them and set them manually?

```
$.each(this.model.attributes, function(index, value){
    // set them manually to undefined
});
```

Comment: I already tried this, but this also wipes out the attribute itself because I am getting errors because of unset properties

Comment: @SjaakRusma, so you want to set all attribute values to `undefined`, but keep the keys of the `attributes` hash?

Comment: I want to set all properties to undefined,

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I recently came across a similar issue - mainly, that if you do unset one-by-one, you get multiple `change` events, with the model in an intermediate state for each one. To allow this to happen with the appropriate change events fired afterwards, you would have to unset them silently one-by-one, then manually fire change events for each one after the unsets. However, if you look at the Backbone code, you'll see that the `unset` method is really just a call to `set`, with `{unset:true}` in the options. So you should be able to do this instead:

```
model.set({ attr1: undefined, attr2: undefined, attr3: undefined }, { unset: true })
```

I haven't tried it in practice, but it should definitely work in theory. You would get a series of `change` events for each attribute, *after* all of the unsets have completed. This approach is going a little outside the recommended path, since it uses unexposed logic from the Backbone source, but since this particular code [hasn't changed in a few years](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/ba7a279f7c65ac4ae0fe787c653d641388093d8f) (and actually appeared to be supported as a `set` option before that), it should be safe to use and continue using.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in method to set all properties undefined, while keeping the `attributes` keys. Good news is that you can easily build one yourself with a underscore one-liner:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.clearValues = function(options) {
  this.set(_.object(_.keys(this.attributes), []), options);
}
```

All models will then have a `clearValues` method:

```
var model = new Model({
  id:1, 
  foo:'foo', 
  bar:'bar'
});
model.clearValues();

console.log(model.toJSON()); //-> {id: undefined, foo: undefined, bar: undefined}
```